# Can't view crossfading image?

Tags: html, css, image, cross-fade

I seemed to have come across a mini roadblock in my HTML/CSS.
I tried to use this crossfade technique in my index and it worked fine but when I tried to use it in my second layout the image wouldn't appear when I opened it? :(

heres the HTML for layout 2:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>

    <title>Welcome!</title>

    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/style.css" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>
<img class="image5" src="../images/header.png" alt="header">
<a href="../index.html"><div id="cf" >
    <img class="bottom2" src="images/logo4.png" alt="logo4"/>
    <img class="top2" src="images/logo3.png" alt="logo3"/>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

---

and here is the CSS for it:

```
.image5 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px; 
    width: 1500px;
    height: 700px;
        }

 #cf {
  position:relative;
  top: 20px;
  left:20px;
  height:277px;
  width:277px;
}

 #cf img {
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
  transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
}

 #cf img.top2:hover {
  opacity:0;
}
```

---

I tried putting it through a validator and it showed two errors:

```
 - Error 1:

Line 20, Column 7: End tag for body seen, but there were unclosed elements.
</body>

 - Error 2:

Line 15, Column 24: Unclosed element a.
<a href="../index.html"><div id="cf">
```

---

I'm not sure what it means by that.
Sorry, I'm still a beginner. ^^;;

Comment: Fix Error 2 and Error 1 will go away.

Comment: Thanks! I fixed it! but the image still wont appear in my second layout D:

Comment: Well some of your images appear to be one directory up (../) and some a child directory (images/) is that correct?

Comment: Well, to debug further we'd need to likely see a working copy. can you upload to JSFiddle?

Comment: how do I upload images on it? :o

Comment: You either have to host the images or just use some sample images hosted elsewhere.

Comment: Ok! so here's how the home page looks like: http://imageshack.com/a/img593/6489/da4j.png
and this is how it looks like when I hover the mouse over:
http://imageshack.com/a/img560/9726/v4m1.png

I tried to do the same thing on the top left on layout two but it looks like this: 
http://imageshack.com/a/img856/8576/03j5.png

Comment: It's hard to debug screen shots, but that last photo shows a broken image link. That means the image is not where your code says it is and/or you have an incorrect file name.

Answer (score 1):

Your css is looking for a tag `#cf` id and then an `img` within it. Maybe it's improper nesting that's messing it up. For your validation errors, you didn't close youre link tag. `<a href ...>` needs to be closed with `</a>`. Try closing it and see if it helps.

Comment: so I should add a "#cf" in my html instead? and I totally forgot about the </a>!! thank you so much! :D

Comment: I'm not sure why it's not working for you tbh. I closed the link tag and I wrote a sample of your code in jsfiddle, and it's working fine:

http://jsfiddle.net/6M36T/

Comment: i tried copying the sample and replacing it with my pictures but it still wouldn't work. I have no idea why it's doing this! D:

Comment: Strange o_O... what size are they? try making them the same size as the ones I used in the example, and see how that goes. If you can host your images somewhere online, run the image from the url instead of as a local file, and then share the fiddle, maybe I can look at it again

Comment: ikr? o - o 
their sizes are:  top: 20px;
  left:20px;
  height:277px;
  width:277px;

oki doki! I'll try uploading it online! :> where do you recommend I upload it to?

Comment: Not sure, photobucket?

Comment: Ok! so here's how the home page looks like: http://imageshack.com/a/img593/6489/da4j.png
and this is how it looks like when I hover the mouse over:
http://imageshack.com/a/img560/9726/v4m1.png

I tried to do the same thing on the top left on layout two but it looks like this: 
http://imageshack.com/a/img856/8576/03j5.png

Comment: Can you post the fiddle?

Comment: For the home page or the page that's causing the problem? :<

Comment: The page causing the problem, like the fiddle i wrote

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/T93Lz/ omg that's so strange!! D: It's working completely fine when I uploaded it on jsfiddle but it wont work when I try to open it in textwrangler ><

Comment: Your link location is probably not pointing to the right place: `<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/style.css" type="text/css">`. Try just changing the body background in that stylesheet with a simple `<html><head><link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/style.css" type="text/css"></head><body></body></html>` file. If that file changes the background then I don't know. If it doesn't, you're link isn't pointing to your stylsheet.